# Storing data of files in other file

Tags: json, xml, file

I want to store file data of a directory in a file. i.e., file name, file size etc so that I can reduce search time. My problem now is to find an efficient way to do it. I have considered json and xml but can't decide between these two. Also if there is a better way let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it's up to what kind of data you prefer to work with and to what structure of data you have (very simple as a list of word,  less simple as a list of word and the number of time each word was searched,...)

For a list of word you can use a simple text file with one word per line or coma separated (csv),  for a less simple structure,  json or xml will work fine.

I like to work with json as it's more light than xml and less verbose.  If you didn't plan to share this data and/or it isn't complex,  you don't need the validation (xsd,...)  offered by xml. 
And even if you plan to share this data,  you can work with json.

You'll need some server side code to write the data to a file,  like php,  java, python,  ruby,...

Comment: Say there R 5000 files if I store file name size and date modified how much delay will it add to read from json file or xml file

Comment: Best way to find out for your case would be to test each case. Create a dummy json and a dummy xml file and try to search in it with a server side language such as php. If you want to provide search based on file size or last edit date it may be an idea to test a database based version too.

Comment: hi Thanks :) But my application is standalone in java.. I'm keeping track of all files so that i don't have open file system everytime

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Json file if you use alomst like a properties file.
If you plan to store the data in the file into database then you can go for XML where u have to the option to use JAXB/JPA in java environment